# AWS Elastic Beanstalk CloudFormation script: unable to sign request without credentials set

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm new to CloudFormation scripts. Trying to build a Beanstalk environment   and it mostly created, except that log streaming configuration fails, and the startup script aborts after that:

```
[2018-06-26T12:28:41.358Z] INFO  [2990]  - [Application deployment/AddonsBefore/ConfigCWLAgent/10-config.sh] : Activity execution failed, because: unable to sign request without credentials set (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
```

caused by: unable to sign request without credentials set (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)

The only related option in the script is this:

```
  - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs
    OptionName: StreamLogs
    Value: true
```

I've started stack creation from the Web console and have not selected any role in CloudFormation so I'm guessing it is using the `aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role` in the instances. Tried to add CloudWatch logs full access to it but the problem didn't go away. The current policies attached are:

```
AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier
CloudWatchLogsFullAccess
AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker
AWSElasticBeanstalkWorkerTier
```

Full script:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'

Parameters:
  ParamDatabaseSpringProfile:
    Description: Select Spring database profile to connect to
    Type: String
    Default: db_h2
    AllowedValues:
      - db_h2
      - db_mysql_test
      - db_mysql_staging
      - db_mysql_prod

  ParamInstanceType:
    Description: Select instance type to create
    Type: String
    Default: t2.micro
    AllowedValues:
      - t2.micro
      - t2.small
      - t2.medium
      - t2.large

Resources:
  pcaBackendApp:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application
    Properties:
      Description: Photo Companion Backend

  pcaBackendVersion100:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion
    Properties:
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: pcaBackendApp
      Description: Photo Companion Backend Version 1.0.0
      SourceBundle:
        S3Bucket: pca-dev-releases
        S3Key: backend-1.0.0.jar

  pcaBackendConfigTemplate:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate
    Properties:
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: pcaBackendApp
      Description: Photo Companion Backend Template
      SolutionStackName: 64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.7.2 running Java 8
      OptionSettings:
      - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
        OptionName: SERVER_CONTEXT_PATH
        Value: /
      - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
        OptionName: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
        Value: !Sub
          - logging_normal, http_insecure, credentials_insecure, ${DbProfile}
          - { DbProfile: !Ref ParamDatabaseSpringProfile }
      - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:asg
        OptionName: MinSize
        Value: '1'
      - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:asg
        OptionName: MaxSize
        Value: '2'
      - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
        OptionName: InstanceType
        Value: !Ref ParamInstanceType
      - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment
        OptionName: EnvironmentType
        Value: LoadBalanced
      - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment
        OptionName: LoadBalancerType
        Value: application
      - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs
        OptionName: StreamLogs
        Value: false # true
      - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:command
        OptionName: DeploymentPolicy
        Value: Rolling
      - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:command
        OptionName: BatchSizeType
        Value: Fixed
      - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:command
        OptionName: BatchSize
        Value: '1'
      - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default
        OptionName: HealthCheckPath
        Value: /actuator/public/health
      - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default
        OptionName: Port
        Value: 8080
      - Namespace: aws:elbv2:listener:default
        OptionName: ListenerEnabled
        Value: false
      - Namespace: aws:elbv2:listener:443
        OptionName: ListenerEnabled
        Value: true
      - Namespace: aws:elbv2:listener:443
        OptionName: Protocol
        Value: HTTPS
      - Namespace: aws:elbv2:listener:443
        OptionName: SSLCertificateArns
        Value: arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:<removed>

  pcaBackendEnvironment100:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment
    Properties:
      ApplicationName:
        Ref: pcaBackendApp
      Description: Photo Companion Backend Environment
      TemplateName:
        Ref: pcaBackendConfigTemplate
      VersionLabel:
        Ref: pcaBackendVersion100
```

Comment: Can you post the full Cloudformation with secrets removed? And what is the bucket policy where you are uploading the application zip?

Comment: Added the script. The bucket is just a default private bucket without any settings. The bucket policy is empty. Note that the script works fine if I set StreamLogs to false so the JAR is downloaded successfully.